# Unable to copy a wchar_t's contents into another wchar_t var which was malloc'd?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a var called `DirToEmpty` which holds the path to the temp dir.

I have another var called `TempBufDir` which will be holding the same value as of `DirToEmpty` but with backslashes escaped.

Example of ***expected behavior***:

```
wchar_t DirToEmpty[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("C:\xxx\yyy\zzz");
wchar_t TempBufDir[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("C:\\xxx\\yyy\\zzz");
```

For this, I malloc'd `TempBufDir`, and tried copying each char from `DirToEmpty` into `TempBufDir`.

Here's the code:

```
// Count number of backslashes
int backslashes = 0;
for (int i = 0; *(DirToEmpty + i); i++) {
    if (*(DirToEmpty + i) == TEXT('\\')) {
        backslashes += 1;
    }
}

// Size of TempBufDir = Length of DirToEmpty + backslashes(escaped) + 1
size_t lpBufSize     = wcslen(DirToEmpty) + backslashes + 1;
wchar_t * TempBufDir = (wchar_t *) malloc (lpBufSize);

if (TempBufDir == NULL) {
    return 9;
}

for (int i = 0, j = 0; *(DirToEmpty)+i; i++, j++) {

    // Copy the char
    *(TempBufDir + i) += *(DirToEmpty + j);

    // If the char is a backslash, add another one to escape it
    // If kth element is a backslash, k+1th element should also be a backslash
    if (*(DirToEmpty + j) == TEXT('\\')) {
        *(TempBufDir + (i + 1)) = TEXT('\\');
    }
}
```

However, the program seems to crash as soon as I execute the program.

***See the screenshot at the bottom of the post.***

**EDIT** : Program seems to quit fine if I remove the last `for` loop. So I assume it's related to the ***buffer size***?

**EDIT 2** : I changed the `malloc` line to:

`wchar_t * TempBufDir = (wchar_t *) malloc (lpBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));`

This hasn't changed anything. Program still crashes.

**EDIT 3** :

[image]

Comment: Looking at the first line of code, should `wchar_t DirToEmpty` be `wchar_t *DirToEmpty`?

Comment: You really must post *actual code*.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem: if you're hardcoding things like `wchar_t` and `wcslen()` you should not use the `TEXT()` macro - just do `L'\\'` instead.

Comment: The value you're passing to malloc is the number of wide-characters needed for the buffer, but malloc needs to know the number of bytes (so `lpBufSize` needs to be multiplied by `sizeof wchar_t`).

Comment: Doesn't `wcslen()` return the length (which is the wide characters)?

Comment: But that is not their size.

Comment: `wcslen()` returns the number of wide-characters in the string, but that's not the number of bytes in the string. For example, `wcslen(L"123")` returns 3, but the buffer needs 8 bytes (accounting for the null terminator).

Comment: It's much easier (for me anyway) when expressions like `*(DirToEmpty + i)` are written as the equivalent `DirToEmpty[i]`.

Comment: The loop at the end is very confused to the point I can't figure out what the variables mean. I would suggest stepping through it line by line to see what is going on and seeing where it doesn't match your intentions.

Comment: The confusion I have is over the loop termination condition, the `+=` the inconsistent incrementing.

Comment: @SatyaPawan: Of course you're free to write your code how you prefer, I'm just letting you know that I think using array indexing for this is easier to read. FWIW I also believe using indexing is probably preferred by most C programmers for these kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the needed doubling of the malloc parameter, there are a bunch of bugs in that loop,

- Inconsistent use of i and j as source and destination indexes
- Wrong loop condition
- Spurious +=
- Forgot to increase i when adding an extra \
- Needs to add 0 terminator

Here is my attempt to fix it:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; *(DirToEmpty+j); i++, j++) {
    *(TempBufDir + i) = *(DirToEmpty + j);

    if (*(DirToEmpty + j) == TEXT('\\')) {
        *(TempBufDir + (i + 1)) = TEXT('\\');
        i++;
    }
}
TempBufDir[i] = 0;
```

By the way, in C, if p is a pointer and i is an integer, *(p+i) is the same as p[i].
You should be using DirToEmpty[i] and not *(DirToEmpty+1).